# Warning message when using cbin() in R

Tags: r, if-statement, vector, cbind

I have a function that match blood type for donors and recipient (Recipient A ---> Donor A or O;
Recipient B ---> Donor B or O;
Recipient O ---> donor O;
Recipient AB ---> donor A, B, O or AB). I keep getting a warning message even though i got the desired output.

1- Here is my data

```
######################
#  Sample data       #
######################
# sample data for recipients

IDr= c(seq(1,5))
BTR=c("A","B","AB","O","O")
data_R=data.frame(IDr,BTR,A=c(0,1,rep(0,3)),B=c(0,rep(0,3),1),C=c(0,rep(1,3),0),D=c(0,rep(1,4)),E=c(1,1,0,rep(1,1),0),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

data_R
  IDr BTR A B C D E
1   1   A 0 0 0 0 1
2   2   B 1 0 1 1 1
3   3  AB 0 0 1 1 0
4   4   O 0 0 1 1 1
5   5   O 0 1 0 1 0

# sample data for donors

IDd= c(seq(1,8))
BTD= c("A","B","AB","O","AB","AB","O","O")
fg= c(rep(0.0025, each=2),rep(0.00125, each=2),rep(0.0011, each=2),rep(0.0015, each=2))
data_D=data.frame(IDd,BTD,A=c(rep(0,5),1,1,1),B=c(rep(0,6),1,1),C=c(rep(1,7),0),D=rep(1,8),E=c(rep(0,5),rep(1,2),0),fg,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# i ordered my data_D
data_D
  IDd BTD A B C D E      fg
2   2   A 0 0 1 1 0 0.00250
4   4  AB 0 0 1 1 0 0.00125
5   5   B 0 0 1 1 0 0.00110
6   6   O 0 0 1 1 0 0.00110
7   7  AB 0 0 1 1 0 0.00150
8   8  AB 1 0 1 1 1 0.00150
1   1   O 1 1 0 1 0 0.00250
3   3   O 1 1 1 1 1 0.00125
```

2- Here is my function that match blood types

```
# my function
  ftest=function(i){
    if(data_R[i,2]=="A"){
      tab=as.data.frame(cbind(data_R[i,1:2],data_D[which((data_D[2]=="A") | (data_D[2]=="O")),][,1:2]))
    }else if(data_R[i,2]=="B"){
      tab=as.data.frame(cbind(data_R[i,1:2],data_D[which((data_D[2]=="B") | (data_D[2]=="O")),][,1:2]))
    }else if(data_R[i,2]=="O"){
      tab=as.data.frame(cbind(data_R[i,1:2],data_D[which (data_D[2]=="O"),][,1:2]))
    }else{
      tab=as.data.frame(cbind(data_R[i,1:2],data_D[,1:2]))
    }
   return(tab)
  }

#  output
 ftest(1)
  IDr BTR IDd BTD
1   1   A   2   A
2   1   A   6   O
3   1   A   1   O
4   1   A   3   O

# Warning message:
# In data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
#  row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded
```

Do you have any idea how to avoid this warning message? Any advise will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: hey welcome to SO. try asking your question in this format. 1) The data you have, 2) What you want to do 3) What you expect 4) What you have tried

Comment: @Onyambu Ok working on it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I think you should try row.names = NULL in your cbind. here is an example from your code

```
tab=as.data.frame(cbind(data_R[i,1:2],data_D[,1:2], row.names = NULL))
```